# TestNG Optional Parameters are being initialized as "not-found" despite specifying default values on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, testng, optional-parameters

Here is a fragment of my code:

```java
@Test 
@Parameters({"author","searchKey"}) 
public void testParameterWithXML(@Optional("You") String author, String searchKey) throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println(author);
```

Upon running this, the output of the first print statement is "not-found" even though I have set a default value (You) for it.

Can someone please explain why?

Comment: Please note: I have not specified any value for the parameter "author" in my testng.xml file . So it is expected to take the default value that I have passed , I guess.

Comment: Should wotk as you expected, could you provide more context, working example?